# Wordpress API - Blog Post Review without admin login

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

We are using in project Wordpress API for displaying blog posts on frontend in our Nuxt 2 app. The problem is that we would like to create possibility of preview blog post's draft without being logged as admin/moderator. I could not find any entries about post draft preview on https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ or about letting everyone to see them. Anyone got any clues?

Comment: Note that if you don't need any authentication, this feature can be "flooded" by bots or users. You really want to let anyone create post (with draft status, but still post) ? I would do some intermediate stuff: a public form, saving post as a custom post type. Then manual/cron script that would run to validate/secure the content, then convert/post it as a post.

Comment: I only want drafts to be visible without authorization ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WP REST API allows you to query posts by post type (API endpoint), and filter by post `status`.
Check documentation about [listing posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/).

> `status`: Limit result set to posts assigned one or more statuses.
>
> `type`: Type of Post for the object.

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=draft

You can use WP post statuses like `publish, future, draft, pending, private`, or custom statuses you made.

Problem is that `private` and `draft` post statuses are protected: those are not public and cannot be queried without authentication. I just tried and indeed, I can query public posts, but I cannot query `private` and `draft` posts without my API request being authenticated.

So what you could do:

1. [Authenticate](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) users to the API so they can query draft and private posts
2. Create a [custom post status](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_status/) that is public (`public`, `publicly_queryable` and `exclude_from_search`  parameters), so it can be queried without authentication from the API. This way you keep `private` and `draft` statuses secured like WP wants it. And use another for "drafts that are public".
3. You can change the "public" status of the `private` and `draft` post statuses, so they can be queried without authentication (see [example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/400658/150390)). Double-check security concerns if doing so, as it would change the WP core status design.

Answer (score 0):

Try a publishing workflow plugin. Lots of them out there. Here's a free one to try...

https://wordpress.org/plugins/publishpress/

I don't know if this reroutes your other processes... but maybe you've already considered this method.